# using ajax to display a message when data get inserted in to the data base

Tags: php, ajax

I've searched through the StackOverFlow but didn't found what I was looking for so I'm posting what I want to ask you.

I'm a new comer to the world of PHP any how I've started to write a script which will get data and display on a WAP interface that part is ok my issue is in the part I'm writing for the data insert page or the Admin page. I've got every thing working but I love to know how to use AJAX to display a message with out going to the particular processing page.

The Process Page,

```
<?php


include ('connect.php');

$data = ("SELECT * FROM poiinfo");

$poiName = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$poiDes = $_REQUEST['Descrip'];
$poiCon = $_REQUEST['ConInfo'];
/*$poiImg = $_REQUEST['Image']; */

$dbData = "INSERT INTO poiinfo(`Name`, `Des.`, `Contact`) VALUES ('$poiName','$poiDes','$poiCon')";

$putData = mysql_query($dbData);

if ($putData){
echo "Data inserted";
}else {
echo "Not Done";
}
?>
```

Can I know how to use AJAX to get an message.

I've used the code examples that you guys gave me but I'm still not getting the job done please can you help me to find what I'm doing wrong.

My Form,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#save_data").click(function(){
var name  = document.getElementById("Name");
var desc = document.getElementById("Descrip");
var con = document.getElementById("ConInfo");

var dataString = 'Name='+name'&Descrip='+desc'&ConInfo='con;
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  data:dataString,
  url:'addpoipro.php',
  success:function(data){
   if(data="Data inserted") {
      alert("Insertion Success");
    } else {
      alert("Not Inserted"); 
    }
    } 
   });
   });
   });
   </script>

   <title>AddPOI</title>
   </head>

   <body>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
   <p>
   <label for="poiid">ID :</label>
   <input type="text" name="poiid" id="poiid" readonly="readonly" style="width:70px;" value="<?php echo $tId; ?>" />
   </p>
   <p>
   <label for="Name">POI Name :</label>

   <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
   </p>
   <p>
   <label for="Descrip" style="alignment-adjust:middle">POI Description :</label>
   <textarea name="Descrip" id="Descrip" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
   <label for="ConInfo">Contact Infomation :</label>
   <textarea name="ConInfo" id="ConInfo" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
   <label for="Img">POI Image :</label>
   <!--<input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" /> -->
   </p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>
   <div align="center">
   <input type="button" name="Submit" id="save_data" value="Submit" style="width:100px;" />
   <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Rest Data" style="width:100px;" />
   </div>
   </p>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Above4 is my form and the process.php is before that please help me thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Example using jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "process.php",
  type: "POST",
  data : { Name : 'John', Descrip : 'some description..', ConInfo : 'some info...' },
  success : function(data){
      if(data == "Data inserted")
      {
          console.log("Success!");
      }
      else
      {
          console.log("fail!");
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but where should I put this part of code in my form or in my process.php

Comment: @SadaruwanSamraweera this is Javascript code, you put it within `<script></script>` tags, and you need to decide how you want to call it, button click? form submit? Don't forget to include the jQuery library.

Comment: thx for the reply yes I know this is a javascript what I was asking is in which page do I've to keep this in the form it self or as a separate file like myjquary.php that's what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without using jquery.

**index.html**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- reply from process.php is shown in this div -->
<div id=message></div>
<!-- click to send data -->
<a href="#" onclick="sendData('John','student','no more info')"> click here </a> 
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function sendData(Name,description,info) {
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        try{
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
        catch (e)
            {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
                try
                    {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                catch (e)
                    {
                        try
                            {
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                        catch (e)
                            {
                            // Something went wrong
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                            }
                    }
            }
        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('message');
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
                { ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;}
                    else { document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="<span style=\"color:green;\">Loading..</span>"; }
                     }
        var url="process.php?name="+Name+"&Descrip="+description+"&ConInfo="+info;
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
        }
```

Comment: You need to encode the query string properly, and why are you sending a `POST` request with no `POST` data?

Comment: sorry my bad :D i used the code i had in my computer. it should be GET

Comment: I like to use your code but like to know can I use    POST with out using    GET

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this also.

**You HTML**

```
<label>Name</labe><input type="text" id="name" name="full_name" value="" />
<label>Address</labe><input type="text" id="addr" name="addr" value="" />
<input type="button" name="save" id="save_data" value="Save" />
```

in the head section after adding jQuery do something like this

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#save_data").click(function(){
    var name  = $("#name").val();
    var addr = $("#addr").val();

    var dataString = 'name='+name'&address='+address;
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:dataString,
      url:'process.php',
      success:function(data){
       if(data="inserted") {
          alert("Insertion Success");
        } else {
          alert("Not Inserted"); 
        }
     } 
   });
  });
});
</script>
```

**"process.php page"**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

// DO YOUR INSERT QUERY
$insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT QUERY GOES HERE");
if(// CHECK FOR AFFECTED ROWS) {
     echo "inserted";
} else {
     echo "not";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the above code I like to vote but still don't have much repo. Any way like to ask about the last part you commented as check for affected rows what is that ?

Comment: The last part is to check if the insertion did took place . Check [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php   for more details